# avoiding automatic software to control web services?

Tags: .net, web-services, security, silverlight, bots

Let's imagine I build a web service, and a client application that call this web service.

Is there any way to prevent other software than mine to make call to the web service ?

For example, imagine a game where a player can gain some money by clicking on an icon, only available once per hour. If the user is connected, well. If the user is not connected, he "loose" the time window to get the money.

In a standard web services + client, it would be quite easy for any teenager to build a script/fake app to execute the web service.

How can I avoid that ?
I know there is no magic solution, but at least, how can I raise difficulty for writing such tools ?

PS: I'm working with Microsoft .Net platform + SilverLigth, but I feel this question is wider that MS technos.

[EDIT] to clarify, I don't ask how to add authentication, but how to avoid a user to automate call to the web services. Nothing prevent a user with an account to use its account to automate the calls; What I want to avoid, is for example, to have a fake app, with an actual authentication, to do something every 5 seconds instead, of on user input. In a game, this can avoid farmer robot

Comment: This is an authentication issue - you need to authenticate your _application_ to the web service.

Comment: @John Saunders: no it is not authentication issue. I assume a hacker can simply register an account and its user/password

Comment: @Steve: authentication does not imply username/password. I mean that your application, itself, needs to establish an identity with the service, perhaps using a certificate.

Comment: @John Saunders: and what can disallow an hacker to reuse its certificate he obtain when registering ?

Comment: @Steve: the certificate would be part of your application. It would not be something that the user generates by registering.

Comment: @John Saunders: the certificate will be not harldy extracted from the application by a hacker (even more if it's .net code)... and again, what disallow the hacker to monitor the http traffic to alter/replay/etc. requests ?

Comment: @Steve: I don't have time to teach you about certificates. The cert would not reside in the application code. Certificates would be useless if they were so easily hackable.

Comment: @John Saunders: for me, certificates have two purposes. either secure the communication channel by exchange session key (which does not prevent a hacker to open itself a session), or be part of the authentication mechanism. In this case, the client, whichever it is, must have the private key... right ? you tell me to embed the private key of the certificate in the app. I still believe the hacker can decompile the app to extract the private key and it's game over. Or I missed some other use of certificates ?

Comment: @Steve: yes, you missed other uses of certificates. I have to go now, but see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

WCF web service methods can be decorated with security requirements. This includes RIA services for Silverlight (which are basically just WCF services).

You can require basic authentication, or even that the user must be a member of a specific role to use a specific method.

This does mean of course that your application must use authentication (i.e. the user must log-in).

Alternatives are to provide your own authentication system (e.g. with tokens), but this still requires the app (at least) to login to the service first to get a new token.

[Edit]
In answer to your followup, robot detection is usually a case of recording durations between calls, or average duration, and simply disallowing access if the limits are exceeded. (or if you are really mean, cancel their account or start returning garbage data)

Comment: this does not answer to my question. Take a look at my edit, I've clarified a bit

Answer (score 0):

You'll want the server to be more aware of the game state. For instance, in the case you outline, the server should be aware whether or not that money icon is on the screen for the user to click on.  When receiving a request for "click on money" it should check if the money is actually on the screen.  Maybe just adding a "last time clicked on money" variable for each user would be enough. But this would allow a bot to "click the money" even if they weren't in the game, although you could limit the frequency.  Perhaps you could go with something more robust.  Such as when displaying a money icon on the screen, include with it a random key value (GUID or something like that) that you can send back with a valid call to verify that they actually clicked on a real money icon that was actually displayed on their screen, as opposed to just click on money icon, you know exactly what they are clicking on. This makes writing a script more difficult, as they would have to look into the memory contents of the game in order to determine the GUID attached to the money icon and submit that along with the request.  This would still be possible, though much more difficult.

Comment: if the server have to check the guid, it must know the guid. That means that the server must have send the guid to the client app... I don't think the hacker will have to scan for memory for that...

Comment: in fact, I feel my only way is to use a captcha mechanism every 15 minutes to prevent bot to handle request. However, that means users will be constrained periodically to use type in this captcha :(

Comment: @Steve, They won't have to, but they will have to establish some kind of ongoing communication with the server.  They will have to initiate some kind of action which will cause the GUID to be sent in the first place, and then, submit the request with the GUID.  So they may not have to scan the memory, but they may have to set up a more complicated system for communicating with the server.  Which may not be worth it in the end.  If you simply limit the frequency, then you at least make it so that they could only do as well as a human playing the game, and not better.

Comment: Also worth noting, even if you require people to click on something on the screen, people can still automate that. I don't know if anybody remembers AllAdvantage and their pay to surf business model.  I know many a people who wrote scripts to browse the web by controlling their actual mouse and clicking around the internet to beat the system.

Comment: I actually remember some kind AllAdvantage that make the application crash on a regular basis, just to force the user to relaunch it (and today there is not such app...easy to understand why). What I conclude, is that I will have to add complexity, to kick off 90% of malicious users, and try to analyse the usage on the server to detect "suspect" usages... not a easy task