# Calling web service from application only

Tags: web-services

I am working on a game app and I want users to be able to record their score on my database so I could keep track of high scores. How do I restrict the web service to only my application? If I use password anyone can reverse engineer app and see password.

Comment: possible duplicate of [avoiding automatic software to control web services ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354546/avoiding-automatic-software-to-control-web-services)

Answer (score 1):

only store the database password on your server.  Use authentication/authorization from the app to your server via https to submit the data to the server.  The server would then insert into the db.  There are 3 tiers here

1. The client apps.  makes http requests to
2. The server app.   does db inserts to
3. The database.

Comment: but that wouldn't stop someone from using their credentials in an app that they created to send a false high score.